# Displaying nested parent-child relationship

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have a table as below with some data:

```
ID        Name       ParentID
-----------------------------
1         A          NULL
2         B          NULL
3         C          1
4         D          2
5         E          3
```

As you can see E is a child of C which is a child of A. I am looking for a simple SQL query which can return a string like below given a child ID, for e.g. ID = 5, which is E should have something as below:

```
Data
-----
A -> C -> E
```

I have tried below query but stuck on way forward

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Name,
       COALESCE(b.Name, '->') AS 'ParentName'
FROM MyTable AS a
LEFT JOIN MyTable  AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.ID = 5
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cte as(
  select * from t where id = 5
  union all
  select t.id, t.name, t.pid from cte c
  join t on c.pid = t.id)
select replace(stuff((select '-' + name from cte
order by id
for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''), '-', '->')
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fdde1/19